# Is short-circuit evaluation possible in multiplication?

Tags: java, math, operators, shortcut, arithmetic-expressions

Suppose I have this code in Java:

```
    public static double function(double x, double y, int k) {
        return Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + y + k*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y, x));
}
```

It calculates some function at certain point `(x,y)`. **Notice** that square root is multiplied by integer `k`. There will be instances where I will give `k = 0` (because I wouldn't need square root evaluated). It gives the value I need **but** the problem is that I am writing time sensitive program, i.e I will call method `function` many, many times. So, I want that my program wouldn't evaluate `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y, x))` if `k = 0`.
I googled a bit, but there doesn't seem to be a 'short-circuit' equivalent for arithmetic (well, in many cases it doesn't even make sense, with multiplication possibly being an exclusion) operations as there is for logic operations.

How could I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think adding ternary operator at the end will avoid calling of `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y, x))` computation. As shown below

```
 public static double function(double x, double y, int k) {
        return Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + y 
             + ( k!=0 ?  k*Math.pow(y, x/2) : 0); //ternary operator here
}
```

Comment: Since it's a time sensitive program you may want to use `k!=0?k*Math.pow(y,x/2):0`, which was over 10% faster than `k!=0 ?  k*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y, x)) : 0` on my machine.

Comment: @Linus Oh yes. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this result by doing

```
k == 0 ? 0 : k*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y, x))
```

This is not equivalent to

```
k*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y, x))
```

though as the shorter version can produce `NaN` even when `k == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a short-circuiting multiplication operator because math just doesn't work that way. What you could do is something like

```
result = Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + y;
if (k != 0)
    result += k*Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y, x));
return result;
```